# Implement a queue type in F# contains elements

Tags: types, f#, queue

I'm implement a queue in F# and works good inserting the elements.

```
// Defines the Queue type as an algebraic data type.
type 'a Queue = QueueList of 'a list * 'a list

let empty = QueueList([], [])

let add elem = function
  | QueueList(top, rest) -> QueueList(top, elem :: rest)
```

I'm stuck trying to verify that if the queue list has the element, return true. If not return false.

```
// Returns true if the queue contains the given element.
val contains: 'a -> 'a Queue -> bool when 'a : equality

// Returns true if the queue contains the given element.
// let rec contains elem = function
       | QueueList([], []) -> false
       | QueueList(hd::tl, tl2) -> if hd = elem 
                                       then true 
                                         else contains elem (QueueList (tl, tl2))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have a few questions here, Why is your queue implementation two lists? do you plan to use a two stack method? what does `top` mean for your queue? If you just want to look throught the `rest` list, you can either use `List.find` or use recursion to navigate and find elements in the list. But your question is not very clear

Comment: I have two lists because, using a tuple of two lists: a list is used to remove items and another list is used to add items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement an immutable queue by using the idea of a list. So you have a top element and the rest of your Queue.

```
type QueueA<'a> =
    | Empty
    | Top   of 'a * QueueA<'a>
```

This is possible; but has bad performance for insertion. Anyway here is how you could implement this kind of Queue.

```
module QueueA =
    let empty = Empty

    let rec add x q =
        match q with
        | Empty        -> Top (x,Empty)
        | Top(y,rest ) -> Top (y, add x rest)

    let head q =
        match q with
        | Empty       -> None
        | Top(x,rest) -> Some x

    let tail q =
        match q with
        | Empty       -> None
        | Top(x,rest) -> Some rest

    let rec iter f q =
        match head q with
        | None   -> ()
        | Some x ->
            f x
            Option.iter (iter f) (tail q)
```

The `add` is not tail-recursive. If you want that the first element stays at the top and further added elements added to the end then you must rebuild the whole Queue. Add is basically a `List.append` where you add an element to the end of the queue rebuilding the whole Queue. So you have slow insertion with quadratic O(x^2) performance.

But `tail` is a fast operation with O(1).

Instead of doing this, you can use two lists for an immutable queue. The idea is: Added elements build a list and you leave them
at the reverse order as long as you don't fetch an element. Only if you want to fetch an element, and no reversed list is avaiable you reverse the list once, and save the reversed list. So adding
an element is O(1) performance.

Fetching an element on the other-side can be O(1) if you already have an reversed list or O(N) if not. Usually you could say it is Amortized O(1).

An implementation looks like

```
type QueueB<'a> = Queue of queue:list<'a> * added:list<'a>

module QueueB =
    let empty     = Queue ([], [])
    let queue q a = Queue (q,a)

    let add x (Queue (q,r)) =
        queue q (x::r)

    let head q =
        match q with
        | Queue([],[]) -> None
        | Queue([],r)  -> Some (List.head (List.rev r))
        | Queue(q,_)   -> Some (List.head q)

    let tail q =
        match q with
        | Queue([],[]) -> None
        | Queue([],r)  ->
            let q = (List.tail (List.rev r))
            Some (queue q [])
        | Queue(h::t,r) ->
            Some (queue t r)

    let rec iter f q =
        match head q with
        | None   -> ()
        | Some x ->
            f x
            Option.iter (iter f) (tail q)
```

For example when you add 1,2,3 to **QueueA**, it will Build the structure

```
Top(1, Top(2, Top(3, Empty)))
```

When you add 1,2,3 to **QueueB**, it will Build the structure

```
Queue([], [3;2;1])
```

When you call `tail` on this you get

```
Queue([2;3], [])
```

Adding 4,5,6 yields

```
Queue([2;3], [6;5;4])
```

Examples

```
(* Top(1, Top(2, Top(3, Empty))) *)
let qs =
    QueueA.empty
    |> QueueA.add 1
    |> QueueA.add 2
    |> QueueA.add 3

(* Queue([], [3;2;1]) *)
let qs =
    QueueB.empty
    |> QueueB.add 1
    |> QueueB.add 2
    |> QueueB.add 3

(* Queue([2;3], [6;5;4]) *)
let qs2 =
    QueueB.tail qs
    |> Option.defaultValue QueueB.empty
    |> QueueB.add 4
    |> QueueB.add 5
    |> QueueB.add 6

(* Prints numbers from 2 to 6 *)
QueueB.iter (printfn "%d") qs2
```

Maybe in a real implementation I would change `head` to also return the remaining Queue (the tail). Because most of the time you probably also will call `tail` if you use `head`. And in this case, the reversing of the list happens twice.

Returning both with `head` only does this once. If you don't need the tail, then you can just throw the tail away.

---

Now, if you want additional functions, you should add a `fold` and `foldBack` function first. For example on QueueB a `fold` will be

```
let rec fold f (state:'State) q =
    let rec loop state q =
        match head q with
        | None      -> state
        | Some head ->
            match tail q with
            | None      -> state
            | Some rest -> loop (f state head) (rest)
    loop state q
```

Then you can implement `contains` with it.

```
let contains x q =
    let folder state e =
        if e = x then true else state
    fold folder false q
```

And with the `qs2` from above

```
QueueB.contains 1 qs2 (* false *)
QueueB.contains 6 qs2 (* true  *)
```

Comment: Thanks, good code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Diego Thanks, if it answers your question, then please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: marks as correct!